# Using Ringtone to detect near and far of a Proximity sensor in android

Tags: java, android, proximity

In my app, I have to play a sound as long as the hand is near the proximity sensor and stop the sound when it is far from the sensor. This is the snippet of the code I use.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),notification);

    if (event.values[0] == 0) {
          r.play();
    }

   else{
        r.stop();
    }
}
```

But my app doesn't work as expected. Even if I move my hand away from the sensor, the ringtone would stop only after it has fully played.

I am new to android programming. So I wasn't able to rectify the errors through the info I get from google search. If the logic is wrong, please tell an other way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `r.stop();` while `r` is null. You say `r =` in the if block, and that's why that part of the code works. But whenever you enter the else instead of the if, `r` is null and your program crashes.

Comment: Got it thanks.. I have edited my question. Can you explain that..?